# Ordery By and Like is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on the autosearch UI where, I need to search the names listed from the letter I search in text box. Ex. You can take as search box works in Google search engine, where when we start entering letters it shows list under that searched text.

Below is the query where I am getting results when using `LIKE` but it is not working as expected, there are two screen shots, currently I am getting the results like first pic.

I even feel even `order by` is also not working.

NOTE :
I need both `Order By`.

Even though there are list which starts from `d` it is not displaying at first.

[image]

Second Pic :

[image]

If you see the second results are coming correct, but why should I remove the wild card syntax under `ProfileName`.

Let me know how I should fix this.

Comment: i agree, I showed only few columns to show it here, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correctly showing what you've written in your query.

The first result shows all records with

- `IsPrimary = 1` AND `LastName` starts with 'd', OR
- `ProfileName` starts with 'd'

The second result shows records with

- `IsPrimary = 1` AND `LastName` starts with 'd', OR
- `ProfileName` = 'd'

Note that `LIKE` is case insensitive.

If you want to prioritize the search to LastName then to ProfileName.

Do this

```
Select * FROM 

(
SELECT [your list here], 1 as priority
FROM Employee E
    INNER JOIN [your list here]
WHERE
    EP.IsPrimary = 1 AND E.LastName LIKE @SearchByChar + '%'

UNION 

SELECT [your list here], 2 as priority
FROM Employee E
    INNER JOIN [your list here]
WHERE
    P.ProfileName LIKE @SearchByChar + '%'
) s

ORDER BY priority
```

Comment: Correct, but I have to use wild card for both of my conditions, I can't give reasons saying we should be using 'Starts with' only to lastname.

Comment: In the second query there's no wildcard so you're checking whether `ProfileName` is equal to 'd', which gives you no result. The checking on `LastName LIKE 'd%'` gives you a list of result with `LastName` starting with 'd'.

Comment: Or, are you trying to prioritize the searching on `LastName`? Then you may use `UNION` joining two queries with separate search.

Comment: Yes, I am prioritizing my search to LastName then to ProfileName.

Comment: You cannot separately order queries joined together by `UNION`. And even if you could, it wouldn't be meaningful because `UNION` does **not** guarantee to return the results from the first result set before it starts returning results from the second (and third, fourth, etc) result set. You need to define a *single* `ORDER BY` clause that can process *all* results from the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `name` matches to appear above profile matches, you could just do something like:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN E.LastName LIKE @SearchByChar + '%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    E.LastName,
    P.ProfileName
```